# 'undefined' elements in the array

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following JavaScript I am using to save selected check boxes:

```
function SubmitCheckBoxes()
{
    alert("test");
    var selectedIDs = [];
    var x = 0;
    a = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        if (a[i].type == "checkbox" ) {
            if (a[i].checked) {
                alert(a[i].value);
                selectedIDs[x] = a[i].value;
                x++;
            }
        }
    }
    $.post('./Courses/SaveAndRedirect', selectedIDs, function (data) { });
}
```

However when I look at the form data being submitted all its says is `undefined: undefined` for each element in the array.

Not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: Congratulations, you've managed to almost completely avoid writing any jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the data attribute in the jquery post method that is wrong. It can't take an array as a parameter. Here is the documentation

> data map or string that is sent to the server with the request.

Try using a object literal instead:

```
$.post('./Courses/SaveAndRedirect', {selectedIDs: selectedIDs}, function (data) { });
```

I would also try writing `selectedIDs[x] = a[i].value;` differently:

```
selectedIDs.push(a[i].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that your post variables are associated with just a numeric instance rather than a field name

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var selectedIDs = [];
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').forEach(function(i, e){
   selectedIDs.push($(e).val());
});
$.post('./Courses/SaveAndRedirect', selectedIDs, function (data) { });
```